# Custom web template not showing in SharePoint online

Tags: office-365, web-template

I have created one sandbox solution in which I am deploying custom web template. It runs successfully when I check the `.wsp` in the on-premise but when I upload the solution to the Office 365 site and set the "Show all site templates" in `Page layouts and site templates` settings, it does not display my custom web template. I searched over internet and found this link which describes the workaround. But one of my colleague said that it is possible to deploy the custom web template with office 365 site.

My web template element is as follows:

```
<WebTemplate BaseTemplateID="39"
           BaseTemplateName="CMSPUBLISHING"
           BaseConfigurationID="0"
           Name="IntranetTemplate"
           Title="Intranet Template"
           DisplayCategory="My Template"
           Description="">

</WebTemplate>
```

I have also checked the feature is activated which provisions the web template element.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Have you inspected the onet.xml file, what is the UIVersion. It should be [UIVersion="15"]

Please go through the following blog for more details. [How to deploy a web template in SharePoint 2013 – Online and on-premise.](http://styledpoint.com/blog/how-to-deploy-a-web-template-in-sharepoint-2013-online-and-on-premise/)

The comment section has some discussion about the troubleshooting the issue you facing.